# Input validation in JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript

I have made a javascript function and want to get the value of that function in a textbox. How can I do this?

My next question is how to put validation to enter numbers only in the textbox?

Answer (score 2):

well, Archinamon made a good job on how to make the js method set a value on the input text , so here is how to validate the input to only accept numbers 
this will accept numbers like 123123123.41212313

```
<input type="text" 
onkeypress="if ( isNaN(this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;"
/>
```

and this will not accept entering the dot (.), so it will only accept integers

```
<input type="text" 
onkeypress="if ( isNaN( String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have provided answers on how to retrieve a value.

For validation, you should learn how to use regular expressions. e.g.

```
function checkPattern()
{
   var re = new RegExp(/^\d+$/);
   if (!re.test(this.value)) {
        this.focus();
        alert("Must be a number!");
   }
}

var inp = document.getElementById('someTextInput');
inp.addEventListener('blur',checkPattern);
```

There are ots of tutorials on the internet about using regular expressions.

Comment: `.setFocus` should be `.focus()`. `.SetFocus` is VB6! :D

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you can do to put vaue in text box:

```
var data = /*call to your function*/
var txtbox = document.getElementById('your textbox id');
txtbox.value = data;
```

for numerical validation try this (on textbox's `onkeypress="fncInputNumericValuesOnly"` ):

```
function fncInputNumericValuesOnly()
{
    if(!(event.keyCode >= 45 && event.keyCode <= 57))
    {
        event.returnValue=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but your `fncInputNumericValuesOnly` is IE only.

Answer (score -1):

```
<textarea id="my_textbox" name="textbox" ...></textarea>
//the row above is simple html

getElementById("my_textbox").value += "something as a string from js function";
```